# How to interpret changing of scroll viewer offset in WP7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I have an image inside a scroll viewer which scrolls horizontally.Is there any way to find the scroll offset or set the maximum value till which the scroll viewer can scroll

Answer (score 2):

The following blog post provides an attached behaviour that exposes the vertical / horizontal offsets of a scrollviewer so that you can bind to them, or set them in code:

http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/07/exposing-and-binding-to-a-silverlight-scrollviewer%E2%80%99s-scrollbars/

This allows the following markup:

```
<ScrollViewer 
    local:ScrollViewerBinding.VerticalOffset="{Binding YPosition, Mode=TwoWay}"
    local:ScrollViewerBinding.HorizontalOffset="{Binding XPosition, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <!-- Big content goes here! -->
</ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.But i have a doubt ,the post u mentioned is focussed for Silverlight users and not Windows Phone 7.Is it right?

Comment: WP7 uses Silverlight as the development platform!

Comment: It does.. but windows programming also uses it.Isn't it?